# Tool to generate class diagram?

Tags: c++, class-design

I have these C++ classes:

```
class sales{
private:
    float dollar[3];
public:
    void getData(float f1,float f2, float f3){
        dollar[0]=f1;// sales of first month
        dollar[1]=f2;// sales of second month
        dollar[2]=f3;// sales of third month
    }
    void putData(){
        int count=0;
        while(count!=3){
        cout<<dollar[count]<<"\t$"<<endl;
        count++;
        }
    }
};


class publication:public sales{
private:
    string PubName;
    int PubYear;
public:
    void SetName(string s){
        PubName=s;
    }
    string GetName(){
        return PubName;
    }
        void SetYear(int y){
        PubYear=y;
    }
    int GetYear(){
        return PubYear;
    }
};

class book:public publication{
private:
    string Author;
public:
    void SetAuthor(string a){
        Author=a;
    }
    string GetAuthor(){
        return Author;
    }


};

class tape:public publication{
private:
    string singer;
public:
    void SetSinger(string s){
        singer=s;
    }
    string GetSinger(){
        return singer;
    }


};
```

I would like to generate a class diagram automatically, is there online useful tool to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StarUML has an reverse engineering option which will generate UML diagram based on your source code (it is free but not online). But normally you should make an diagram before writing any line of code.

Answer (score 2):

use [doxygen](http://doxygen.org) it is easy to use, gives you your graphs out of the box and is excellent to document your code - best of all: it is free.

Comment: Forgot about that - good call on the doxygen - its cheaper then my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few (look for reverse code engineering). Personally I user Enterprise Architect from http://www.sparxsystems.com/

Answer (score 0):

This might be more than you need, but you  might try ArgoUML:

[ArgoUML home page](http://argouml.tigris.org/)

If you use the Web start link, it's almost like an online tool.